# Make singleton pattern code stronger

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

```
public class SingletonDoubleCheckedLock {
    private volatile static SingletonDoubleCheckedLock uniqueInstance;

    private SingletonDoubleCheckedLock() {
    }

    public static SingletonDoubleCheckedLock getInstance() {
            if (uniqueInstance == null) {
                    synchronized (SingletonDoubleCheckedLock.class) {
                            if (uniqueInstance == null) {
                                    uniqueInstance = new SingletonDoubleCheckedLock();
                            }
                    }
            }
            return uniqueInstance;
    }
}
```

If any error occurs when running the `getInstance()` method (e.g. when executing `new SingletonDoubleCheckedLock()` but there isn't enough memory) and I still want the  `getInstance()` method return the right result. How to achieve this?

Comment: *"If any error occurs then..."* Then what? getInstance() will throw an exception. What exactly is the behavior you expect?

Comment: AFAIK the best way to implement a singleton in Java is through an `enum`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/71399/1825094).

Comment: If you consider `enum` hacky, the [Spring framework](http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/) has set up singletons for years.

Comment: Is it me, or are you checking one condition two times in a row without doing anything?

Comment: 2 things: 1: your instance does not need to be volatile. 2: you can synchronize the getInstance() method and lose the synchronized block within. Only check for null once.

Comment: @NickJ Making the method synchronized would potentially create a fairly large performance hit if many calls are made to getInstance() simultaneously.  Declaring the instance as volatile is also importance and Java's memory model does not handle double-checked locking well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#Usage_in_Java

Comment: I am aware that enclosing too much in synchronized blocks is a performance hit, but I stand by my comment because by far the most expensive operation in `getInstance()` is creating the instance, which would need to be synchronized anyway. Checking the existance if relative cheap, and also needs to be in the same synchronised block, so you may as well just synchronize the method. Volatile is unnecessary because `uniqueInstance' is only ever accessed from the same synchronized block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question: "If any error occurs when running the getInstance() method ... and I still want the getInstance() method return the right result. How to achieve this?"

Short answer: you can't guarantee it.

There are a large number of conditions which can throw a `Throwable`

There are 2 main types (subclasses) of `Throwable` : `Exception` and `Error`.

`Exception` is used to indicate a condition which may arise in the application to prevent normal flow of execution, and the application may catch and correct the situation before continuing. Some forms of Exception (checked exceptions) have to be caught eventually.

`Error` is used to indicate a seriously abnormal condition from which the application cannot be expected to recover, the cause of which is probably beyond the application's control. You can catch an Error but there's not much point as the situation probably cannot be recovered.

As you can see, if your `getInstance()` throws an error, there's nothing you can do whilst the application is running. You only have a sporting chance of recovery if an Exception occurs.